# How should I handle a leave animation in componentWillUnmount in React?

Tags: javascript, animation, reactjs, gsap

I was wondering if anyone could provide some insight about how they handle leave animations in React.js. I have been using Greensock TweenMax and the enter animations work fine on `componentDidMount`, but I haven't found a reliable way to animate a component out.

My feeling is that it should go in `componentWillUnmount`, but React provides no callback mechanism for you to indicate when you are ready to let go of a component. Therefore the transition animation never completes since the animations are asynchronous to React. Instead, you see a tiny fraction of a second of animation, the component disappears, and is replaced by the next component animating in.

This is a problem I have struggled with since I started using React 9 months ago. I can't help but think there has to be a solution out there other than `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` which I find to be cumbersome and finicky, especially with react-router.

Comment: You should do it in two steps where a component leaving is marked with some local state in the component, which triggers the animation. When the animation is complete, it can notify the parent to remove it completely.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`ReactTransitionGroup` (upon which `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` is built) is the base component that allows asynchronous entering and leaving. It provides lifecycle hooks that you can use to hook into JS-based animations. [The docs list](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html#low-level-api-reacttransitiongroup) the allowed hooks:

> `ReactTransitionGroup` is the basis for animations. When children are declaratively added or removed from it (as in the example above) special lifecycle hooks are called on them. There are 3 ways to get starting using `ReactCSSTransitionGroups`:

```javascript
import ReactCSSTransitionGroup from 'react-addons-css-transition-group' // ES6
var ReactCSSTransitionGroup = require('react-addons-css-transition-group') // ES5 with npm
var ReactCSSTransitionGroup = React.addons.CSSTransitionGroup; // ES5 with react-with-addons.js
```

> **`componentWillAppear(callback)`**
>
> This is called at the same time as `componentDidMount()` for components that are initially mounted in a `TransitionGroup`. It will block other animations from occurring until `callback` is called. It is only called on the initial render of a `TransitionGroup`.
>
> **`componentDidAppear()`**
>
> This is called after the `callback` function that was passed to `componentWillAppear` is called.
>
> **`componentWillEnter(callback)`**
>
> This is called at the same time as `componentDidMount()` for components added to an existing `TransitionGroup`. It will block other animations from occurring until `callback` is called. It will not be called on the initial render of a `TransitionGroup`.
>
> **`componentDidEnter()`**
>
> This is called after the `callback` function that was passed to `componentWillEnter` is called.
>
> **`componentWillLeave(callback)`**
>
> This is called when the child has been removed from the `ReactTransitionGroup`. Though the child has been removed, `ReactTransitionGroup` will keep it in the DOM until `callback` is called.
>
> **`componentDidLeave()`**
>
> This is called when the `willLeave` `callback` is called (at the same time as `componentWillUnmount`).

<sup>[Animation - Low-level API](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html#low-level-api-reacttransitiongroup)</sup>

In order to animate a child out, you'd need to start your animation in `componentWillLeave` and call the provided `callback` when the animation is complete. As an example, [here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/f51jbw2k/) showing a component that stagger-animates its children in and out: http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/f51jbw2k/

The relevant code for animating out is:

```javascript
componentWillLeave: function(callback) {
  this._animateOut(callback);
},

_animateOut(callback) {
  var el = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);
  setTimeout(function() {
    TweenLite.to(el, 1, {opacity: 0}).play().eventCallback("onComplete", callback);
  }, this.props.animateOutDelay);
},
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this explanation. This is the most clear and concise explanation I have ever found of animation within the component lifecycle.

Comment: ReactTransitionGroup animation is just horrible

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: React.findDOMNode is not a function`

Comment: @Green: it's `ReactDOM.findDOMNode` nowadays

Comment: Spent most of the day on this. ReactTransitionGroup doesn't support interrupting the animation and then playing it in reverse, it always has to wait for the previous animation to end. Sucks if the users is clicking things quickly, would rather have no animations than unresponsive ones. If you're using any higher order components they won't pass down your life cycle methods (e.g. redux's connect)

Comment: What about a slide mechanism for sliding out an UNMOUNTED component, while sliding in a new MOUNTED component? I can't seem to get this to work w/o trickery.

Comment: @Ally , use React-Motion to fix this. It uses javascript to perform the animation but allows for a seamless transition. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1tavDv5hXpo

Comment: @jamesemanon https://github.com/chenglou/react-motion#transitionmotion- allows for this behaviour. It looks complicated at first, but once you figure it out, it's very flexible.

Comment: For me ReactTransitionGroup doesn't even import, says i'm trying to load more than one copy of React. Following the sample example from React native page creates this error. Here's the problem: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3970.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [React-Motion](https://github.com/chenglou/react-motion)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1tavDv5hXpo

Cheng Lou is a developer on the React team.

He talks about the issues with the current ReactCSSTransitionGroup.

He has developed [React-Motion](https://github.com/chenglou/react-motion) for fixing this issue.

Although it doesn't use css transitions , it seems to perform well and is very deterministic. Where as ReactCSSTransitionGroup seems to be finicky as you cannot interrupt transitions.

Comment: `react-motion` is hardly a replacement for CSSTransitionGroup, it's miles away from being humanly usable for effects that are otherwise trivial do do with CSS class transitions and keyframe animations.

Comment: I do agree, its fairly complicated to use.

Comment: I found this FAAAR simpler to use than anything provided by React-Transition-Group. Thanks for pointing this out!